# A little hazy about std::ref() and std::bind() with variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates

I have read many posts about variadic templates and std::bind but I think I am still not understanding how they work together.  I think my concepts are a little hazy when it comes to using variadic templates, what std::bind is used for and how they all tie together.

In the following code my lambda uses the dot operator with objects of type TestClass but even when I pass in objects of type std::ref they still work.  How is this exactly?  How does the implicit conversion happen?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
using std::forward;

class TestClass {
public:
    TestClass(const TestClass& other) {
        this->integer = other.integer;
        cout << "Copy constructed" << endl;
    }
    TestClass() : integer(0) {
        cout << "Default constructed" << endl;
    }
    TestClass(TestClass&& other) {
        cout << "Move constructed" << endl;
        this->integer = other.integer;
    }

    int integer;
};

template <typename FunctionType, typename ...Args>
void my_function(FunctionType function, Args&&... args) {
    cout << "in function" << endl;
    auto bound_function = std::bind(function, args...);
    bound_function();
}

int main() {

    auto my_lambda = [](const auto& one, const auto& two) {
        cout << one.integer << two.integer << endl;
    };

    TestClass test1;
    TestClass test2;
    my_function(my_lambda, std::ref(test1), std::ref(test2));

    return 0;
}
```

More specifically, I pass in two instances of a reference_wrapper with the two `TestClass` objects `test1` and `test2`, but when I pass them to the lambda the `.` operator works magically.  I would expect that you have use the `::get()` function in the reference_wrapper to make this work but the call to the `.integer` data member works..

Comment: *"How does the implicit conversion happen?"* - implicit conversion between what types?

Comment: I will update my question to be more clear.  Sorry about that

Comment: @soon There! Does that make my question more clear?

Comment: Yes, I understand your question now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reference unwrapping is performed by the result of [`std::bind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind#Member_function_operator.28.29):

> If the argument is of type `std::reference_wrapper<T>` (for example, `std::ref` or `std::cref` was used in the initial call to `bind`), then the reference `T&` stored in the bound argument is passed to the invocable object.

Corresponding standardese can be found in N4140 draft, [func.bind.bind]/10.

Comment: Wow! That is so magical.  Also could you suggest somewhere I could learn more about these std::bind and variadic templates from?  Because currently they seem to be like magic to me and I can't really program when things seem like magic...

Comment: @Curious [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/3959454)

Comment: @Curious: it's worth mentioning you should probably study bind and variadic templates seperately.  They don't have any unusual interactions, bind acts exactly the same with or without variadics, and variadics act exactly the same with or without bind.  As such, it's less of a head-overload to study them seperately.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that with [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind);

> The arguments to `bind` are copied or moved, and are never passed by reference unless wrapped in `std::ref` or `std::cref`.

The "passed by reference" above is achieved because `std::ref` provides a result of [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) that is a value type that "wraps" the reference provided.

> `std::reference_wrapper` is a class template that wraps a reference in a copyable, assignable object. It is frequently used as a mechanism to store references inside standard containers (like `std::vector`) which cannot normally hold references.

By way of an example of what `bind`'s unwrapping of the reference does (without the `bind`);

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int a = 1;
    auto b = std::ref(a);
    int& c = b;
    cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << endl; // prints 1 1 1
    c = 2;
    cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << endl; // prints 2 2 2
}
```

[Demo code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fbf3828e3801fb6).